# Adding / removing rows in v-for loop with file input preview

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a v-for loop with a text field and a file input, I can add a new row at the next index of any item in the loop using the buttons on that item. The new item will initially be a copy of the previous item but can be changed independently.

This works if you try it with just the text field, the problem is when I select an image and then add a new row in-between indexes, the file preview does not update correctly, the actual object seems to be correct if you look at the string on each row.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbMXbN?editors=1111)

Try this:
Add 2 new rows (3 total), select an image in the 2nd row, now try and add a new row from the first, this pushes a new row after the first row which now should push the row with the image down to the 3rd, it seems to do this but the thumbnail also stays in the 2nd.

I have been building this component and messing around with it for a while so maybe i'm just missing where I need to be updating or watching somewhere.

```
Vue.component("file-drop-zone", {
  data() {
    return {
      draggingFile: false,
      previewFiles: [],
      files: [],
      input: null
    };
  },
  props: ["setItems", "returnDataUrl"],
  mounted() {
    this.input = this.$refs.fileInput;
  },
  created() {
    console.log("this.setItems", this.setItems);
    if (this.setItems) {
      this.loadFiles(this.setItems);
      this.input = null;

    }
  },
  methods: {
    openFileExplorer() {
      this.input.click();
    },
    onFileSelection() {
      // add all selected files
      const filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.input.files);
      // show previews
      this.loadFiles(filesArr);
      // reset file input
      this.input.value = null;
    },
    dropFiles(e) {
      const filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.dataTransfer.files);
      this.loadFiles(filesArr);
    },
    loadFiles(filesArr) {
      let self = this;
      self.draggingFile = false;
      // const files = e.dataTransfer.files
      // let filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files)

      filesArr.forEach(function(f) {
        // let resizedImage = self.rs(f)
        // console.log('f', f)
        let filename = f.name;
        let extenstion = filename.split(".").reverse()[0];
        // console.log(extenstion)
        const mimeType = f.type;
        // console.log(f.type)

        if (!f.type.match(/image.*/)) {
          let promise = self.getBase64(f, self.updateFilesArr());
          promise.then(function(result) {
            // console.log(result)
            let dataUrl = result.reader;
            self.previewFiles.push({
              name: result.file.name,
              src: dataUrl,
              ext: extenstion,
              type: mimeType
            });
            let blob = self.dataURItoBlob(dataUrl, filename, extenstion);
            let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: blob.type });
            self.files.push(file);
            self.updateFilesArr();
            // console.log('result', blob)
          });
        } else {
          self.rs(f);
        }
      });
    },
    async rs(f) {
      const self = this;
      const config = {
        file: f,
        maxSize: 1024
      };
      const resizedImage = await self.resizeImage(config).then(res => {
        self.files.push(res);
        self.updateFilesArr();
        // console.log('upload res', res)
      });
      console.log("resizedImage", resizedImage);

      return resizedImage;
    },
    updateFilesArr() {
      // let finalFiles = _.cloneDeep(this.files)
      if (this.returnDataUrl) {
        this.$emit("listen-update-files", this.previewFiles);
      } else {
        this.$emit("listen-update-files", this.files);
      }
      this.$refs.fileInput = this.files;
    },
    removeFile(file) {
      // console.log('remove file', file)
      // remove from preview array
      this.previewFiles.splice(
        _.findKey(this.previewFiles, { name: file.name }),
        1
      );
      // remove from file array
      this.files.splice(_.findKey(this.files, { name: file.name }), 1);
      this.updateFilesArr();
    },
    getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
          resolve({ reader: reader.result, file: file });
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    },
    resizeImage(settings) {
      const self = this;
      let file = settings.file;
      let filename = file.name;
      let mimeType = file.type;
      let extenstion = filename.split(".").reverse()[0];
      let maxSize = settings.maxSize;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let image = new Image();
      let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

      let resize = function() {
        let width = image.width;
        let height = image.height;
        if (width > height) {
          if (width > maxSize) {
            height *= maxSize / width;
            width = maxSize;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > maxSize) {
            width *= maxSize / height;
            height = maxSize;
          }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
        let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        self.previewFiles.push({
          name: filename,
          src: dataUrl,
          ext: extenstion,
          type: mimeType
        });
        let blob = self.dataURItoBlob(dataUrl, filename, extenstion);
        return new File([blob], filename, { type: blob.type });
      };
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
          image.onload = function() {
            return resolve(resize());
          };
          image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    },
    dataURItoBlob(dataURI, filename = null, ext = null) {
      var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
      var mimeString = dataURI
        .split(",")[0]
        .split(":")[1]
        .split(";")[0];
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      var bb = new Blob([ab], {
        type: mimeString
      });
      bb.name = filename;
      bb.ext = ext;
      return bb;
    }
  },
  template: `
<v-container fluid pa-0 ma-0 style="height:100%">
<input
      ref="fileInput"
      type="file"
      name="files[]"
      :multiple="true"
      @change="onFileSelection"
    />

<v-container
      @dragenter="draggingFile = true"
      @dragleave="draggingFile = false"
      @drop.prevent="dropFiles"
      @dragover.prevent="draggingFile = true"
      fluid
      grid-list-lg
      :class="['dropzone', draggingFile ? 'dropzone-over' : '']"
    >
      <v-layout row wrap align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex xs12 text-xs-center>
          <span class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light"
            >Drop files here or
            <a @click.prevent="openFileExplorer">browse...</a></span
          >
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex
          xs12
         sm4
          v-for="(file, i) in previewFiles"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-card flat outlined>
            <v-img

              :src="file.src"
              height="150px"
            >
              <v-container fill-height fluid>
                <v-layout fill-height>
                  <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox pa-0>
                    <span
                      class="white--text"
                      v-text="file.name"
                      style="word-break: break-all;"
                    ></span>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
            </v-img>



            <v-card-actions
              class="white black--text"
              style="border-top:solid 1px #ccc !important;"
            >
              <v-layout justify-center row wrap>
                <v-flex shrink>
                  <v-btn icon color="error" @click="removeFile(file)">
                    <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>

</v-container>
 `
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    areaObject: {
      text: "",
      images: []
    },
    areas: [],
    final: []
  }),
  created() {
    this.areas.push(this.areaObject);
  },
  watch: {
    areas: {
      handler(val) {
        this.final = _.cloneDeep(val);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addArea(i) {
      this.areas.splice(i + 1, 0, {
        text: this.areas[i].text,
        images: this.areas[i].images
      });
    },
    removeArea(i) {
      if (this.areas.length > 1) {
        this.areas.splice(i, 1);
      }
    },
    updateImages(i, payload) {
      this.areas[i].images = payload;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i took a deeper look. Lets see, mistakes:

```
 <v-card flat width="100%" v-for="(item, i) in areas" :key="`card${i}`" class="my-2">
```

This means that the id of each item depends on its position... Not such a good idea, as you'll see.

Clones the first image view.

```
    addArea(i) {
      this.areas.splice(i + 1, 0, {
        text: this.areas[i].text,
        images: this.areas[i].images
      });
```

Second, your images aren't even used for rendering.

```
    updateImages(i, payload) {
      this.areas[i].images = payload;
    }
```

Take a good look at this (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oroRNK) and consider it. I added an id tag together with the previewFiles in each `file-drop-zone`.

Vue doesn't care about how you modify the array by splicing. Observe how new ids are added to the back regardless.

This is because of your keys.

To fix that, do this, simply fix the keys. (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqXBjM)

Normally this isn't a problem, except that there exists state in your file-drop-zone isn't entirely encapsulated in the parent. A combination of both mistakes causes it to update wrongly.

Comment: The resizeImage() method is called when the loadFiles() method is called in the created() hook which fires when a new area is added - the resizeImage() method sorts out the previewFiles

Comment: @MattStudios i took a closer look at it and have summarized my findings.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for looking in to it